# How can I update the parent state in React from a child funcional componet?

Tags: reactjs, fluentui-react, powerapps-modeldriven

I need bind states between two components (a navbar an a map). Both components are receiving data from index state via props.

How can I update index state in navbar component in order to update map component?

In index.ts init

```
this.state: { routes: {geojson_routes}, loadaded: false }
```

In navbar.tsx

```
const [routes, setRoutes] = React.useState(props.routes)
const [loaded, setLoaled] = React.useState(props.loaded)

const showRoute= () => {
    setLoaled(true)
}
```

In map.tsx

```
if(props.loaded == true) show = geojason(props)
```

I guess what I need is when showRoute is call from navbar, update loaded value from index.ts... But I don't know how ¬¬'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a function that sets the `loaded` state to true to the Navbar component as a prop. Then, when you want to set `loaded` to true, call the function from the navbar component.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Now I have state like "this.state = {routes="geojson", loaded: false, load: () => this.state.loaded = true};" passed as props to the Navbar component. I can call it from there, but it does not execute the updateView.